# How to populate FilePond with File object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

Hello I have a FilePond instance:

```
<FilePond
    ref={ref => this.pond = ref}
    oninit={() => this.handleInit() }
    onupdatefiles={(files) => this.props.setFile(files[0])}
/>
```

When you upload a file it calls `setFile()` which saves it to the state of the parent component. From there I am trying to add this file uploaded to a different FilePond instance that is also a child of the parent component this is being set to. Here is how I am currently trying this:

```
<FilePond
    ref={ref => this.pond = ref}
    oninit={() => this.pond.addFile(this.props.chosenFile) }
/>
```

So here's the flow of the file object

CHILD1 --Set file in state--> PARENT --Pass down file--> CHILD2

Here is what CHILD2's filepond looks like after setting it
[image: undefined filepond]

Here is the file object being passed around
[image: fileobject]

Here is an error I see in the console
[image: error]

I've read the [docs](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/react/) and they don't seem to have an example of populating a FilePond with a file object they give you. I have been stuck on this for a while any help would be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Author of FilePond here, I'm not sure this is related to FilePond itself but I thought I'd give it a shot.

It seems both ponds set `this.pond` as a reference, I guess as both have the same parent component they should each have a unique reference.